# Hide specific row from table without ID

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have simple table generated by PHP.

```
<table border="1" id="control>
    <tbody>
        <tr>...</tr>
        <tr>...</tr>
        <tr>...</tr>  //Row #3
        <tr>...</tr>
        <tr>...</tr>
        <tr>...</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to hide 3rd row when page loads using javascript or css. Is there any way to do this without giving 3rd row ID?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The JavaScript answers here are using `.getElementsByTagName()`. The idiomatic means of accessing table rows by index is to use the native collections that are specific to table rows and cells. For example: `document.getElementById("#control").rows[2].style.display = "none";`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with css3 you can use the :nth-child selector

```
#control tr:nth-child(3)
{
   display:none;
}
```

Comment: Note that this will only work where CSS3 selectors are implemented, meaning that IE8 and previous versions will not support it.

Answer (score 5):

using jquery its pretty simple, `$('#control tr:eq(2)').hide()`

Comment: I do not really want to use jQuery but if there is no other way I will. Thank you for example.

Comment: if you are not using jquery, you can also use the querySelectorAll method, like this `document.querySelectorAll('#control tr')[2].style.display = "none";`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[2].style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 1):

Using pure JavaScript (no framework like JQuery etc.) one can do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1" id="control">
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>row1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>row2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>row3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>row4</td></tr>
            <tr><td>row5</td></tr>
            <tr><td>row6</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var tableElm = document.getElementById("control");
        var tableChilds = tableElm.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        var row3 = tableChilds[2];
        row3.style.display = "none";
        // alternatively:
        //row3.style.visibility = "hidden";
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [`eq(int)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to select the row at the zero-based index:

```
$("#control tr").eq(2).hide();
```